# Import media on python gives Import Error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-import, python-module

Here is the piece of code:

```
from PIL import Image
from pygraphics import media

toy_story = media.Movie()
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'Image'
```

If I comment out the `from pygraphics import media` line it works. But then I need the `media` package. what's going on here. I have installed all the required packages by doing `pip install <module name>`. If I comment out `from PIL import Image` I still get the same error. What is going on here?. I have looked at other similar questions on here. But none of them answer this question.

**TL;DR** `import media` doesn't work. It gives the error `ImportError: No module named 'Image'`. But I have already installed Image via PIL. Help!!

I am on a mac and using python 3.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal, run `python3 -m pip install <module_name>`. `pip` has likely installed the module for python2, which you can verify by running `help("modules")` in python2 and python3. Running `pip -V` will also tell you which version of Python `pip` is installing modules for.

Comment: I have installed python using Anaconda. The modules are installed for the correct version of python that  I am trying to compile from.

Comment: @JackDawkins So, do you see PIL _and_ pygraphics when you run `help("modules")` in Python 3.5.1?

Comment: When I do `help ("modules")` they don't show. But when I do them individually they do show help: `help ("PIL")`and  `help ("pygraphics")`